# Creating session after sending response to client

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to execute a method(which takes a long time for execution) immediately after sending response from controller without having to keep the client wait for response.

My source code for sending the response is as follows,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "exportExcelReportService", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public void exportExcelReportServiceGetJsonObject(@ModelAttribute ReqParam reqParam, HttpServletResponse response) {
    java.io.PrintWriter wr;
    try {
        wr = response.getWriter();

    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    wr.print(response);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    exportDataUsingVMService.getByteArrayForExcelSheet(reqParam);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Over here getByteArrayForExcelSheet will get executed after the response has been sent to client. But I'm unable to create session in this method,

```
public void getByteArrayForExcelSheet(ReqParam reqParam) {

        JSONObject jObject = null;

        HttpSession httpsession = request.getSession(false);

}
```

Where request is autowired like this,

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;
```

I get exception in `getByteArrayForExcelSheet` like this,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
```

Comment: Create the session before you send the response; the session requires a cookie; and the cookie must be sent as a header. Thus you must create the session first (but you can pass it to your method).

Comment: Thank you very much @ElliottFrisch, I attached the httpsession to reqParam before sending the response, like this, reqParam.setHttpsession(request.getSession()); then I used it in my getByteArrayForExcelSheet method.